# Process unknown varied HTML markup into PDF using MigraDoc

Tags: c#, asp.net, migradoc

In an ASP.NET app written in C#, I have been using MigraDoc to produce PDF files. It works well with just text.

But we have some fields that are HTML enabled by means of editors like TinyMCE. In some fields there could be just two  paragraphs, in some there could a paragraph and a list with 3 items, another field could have just a table.

If I knew in advance what these fields will have then I can strip HTML and use MigraDoc to produce PDF without losing a formatting.

If I don't know the HTML content in advance, is there a way to produce PDF using MigraDoc or any other plugin, possible solutions?